# Trying Atom integrate with github.com

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I'm using atom for coding in assembly and I'm trying pushing my commits to my git-hub repository. I downloaded git-plus package but every-time i do push I receiving this error massage:

> "fatal could not read username for [https://github.com](http://github.com) no such device
>   or address"

when I do push using the terminal it works.

Answer (score 0):

Link your git remotely by these commands:

git remote rm origin and 
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a remote for your repository:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
```

Where `user` in the link is your name in e.g. GitHub and `repo` is the name of your repository.